Jquery onClick not working on Iphones but working on androids
So I have this code:
$(".left-nav-icon").on("click touchstart", function () {
  $(".nav_aside").toggleClass("show");
});

It's meant to display a sidebar when I click on a .left-nav-icon. It works perfectly on android but for some reason, just doesn't work on ios. I've tried everything, this was the last code I tried and it still didn't work.
I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Have you tried using only click without the touchstart?

@beth yes I have, did not work

Try writing your code like this instead. Updated code:


 $(".left-nav-icon").click(function() {
     $(".nav_aside").toggleClass("show");
  });
.nav_aside{
    display: none;
  }
  
  .nav_aside.show{
    display: block;
  }
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   
   <div id="container">
        <h1 class="left-nav-icon">Menu</h1> 
         <h1 class="nav_aside">Sidebar</h1> 
        <h1 class="nav_asides">Content</h1> 
     </div>




Now it's not even working on android

This is the most direct way you can create a toggle function in jQuery, do you get any error on your console when you click the menu? Also, if you can provide THE HTML and CSS section that would be helpful. and if the website is live you can provide the link.

https://bet.theumpire.io ....this is the site. The button I'm interested in is the blue button on the left of the page

Your website is redirected to a 404 page, but I have updated the code above so that you can run the code and see it work, cross-check your CSS is well defined too.

I updated something on it. But it's not redirecting to 404 anymore.

I tried your code, it's almost the same as what I'm running now. And it works on localhost but not on cpanel

Unfortunately, I don't have an iPhone and can't test my answer, but I guess it works.
Before I try to present my solution, let me say one thing, .on('click' is usually used for live element. If your element is not live, it is better to use this.
$(".left-nav-icon").click(function() {
    $(".nav_aside").toggleClass("show");
});

But my solution is:
1-  make sure there is no element on .left-nav-icon. It may be, for example, a part of a div on the .left-nav-icon element (in iphone). This way your click on the .left-nav-icon will not be applied. this code can help you
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.target)
})

2- It is better to use raw JavaScript, this code is equivalent to your code:
document.querySelectorAll('.left-nav-icon').forEach(elm=>{
    elm.addEventListener('click',function(){
        this.classList.contains('show')?
            this.classList.remove('show'):
            this.classList.add('show')
    })
})

